SwiftUI Chart Extend data point to full width of graph
I've been playing around with SwiftUI charts lately and there is so many modifiers to learn about lol. I was wondering if anyone can help me extend the data points from the starting left side of the graph to the right side so it covers the whole width of the chart. As you can see, each point is centred for every individual AxisMark for the day of the week that aligns with the axis value label.
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Chart(weight) { data in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Day", data.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Weight", data.weight)
                )
                .symbol {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.pink)
                        .frame(width: 8)
                }

                RuleMark(y: .value("Goal Weight", 63))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.secondary)
                    .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.8, dash: [10]))
                    .annotation(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                        Text("Your Goal:  63 kg")
                            .font(.subheadline).bold()
                            .padding(.trailing, 32)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.secondary)
                    }
                
                ForEach(weight) { data in
                    AreaMark(
                        x: .value("Day", data.date, unit: .day),
                        yStart: .value("WeightLow", 63),
                        yEnd: .value("WeightLow",  data.weight)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(gradientColor)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 400)
            .foregroundStyle(.pink)
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day)) { _ in
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.weekday(.abbreviated), centered: true)
                }
            }
            .chartYScale(domain: 62...70)
        }
        .padding()
    }



found the answer, the unit value on the x-axis is unnecessary as its an ordinal value. If you remove it, then everything works as expected. So wherever I had unit: .day in my example. Just remove it from there
